# Do The Eigenvectors of a Positive Semi-Definite matrix span the column space.

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have a matrix B=A'A , where ' denote transpose, is a Symmetric Positive Semi definite matrix.
Does the Eigenvectors of B spans the column space of B?

Thank you.

Comment: An eigenvector of a positive semidefinite matrix may not be in the column space, e.g., the eigenvector $(2,-1)$ is not in the column space of $\pmatrix{1&2\cr2&4\cr}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$A=\pmatrix{0&0\cr1&2\cr}$$ Then $$B=A^tA=\pmatrix{0&1\cr0&2\cr}\pmatrix{0&0\cr1&2\cr}=\pmatrix{1&2\cr2&4\cr}$$ $B$ has eigenvalues $0$ and $5$ with eigenvectors $(2,-1)$ and $(1,2)$, respectively, so it is positive semi-definite. Those eigenvectors span all of ${\bf R}^2$, but the column space of $B$ is one-dimensional, spanned by $(1,2)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but do the eigenvectors corresponds to the nonzero eigenvalues span the the column space of the matrix?

Comment: The concept of "positive semi-definite" is only defined for symmetric matrices. The eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix form a basis for ${\bf R}^n$. Every eigenvector is in the column space of the matrix. The number of nonzero eigenvectors (that is, eigenvectors for nonzero eigenvalues) equals the dimension of the column space. Put that all together, and it says, yes, the eigenvectors for the nonzero eigenvalues span the column space.

Comment: Does that do it?

Comment: Yes, Indeed. Many Thanks.